# Is possible to execute an operator (OT) from code and SHOW its UNDO panel?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, operator, panel

Hello folks I'm trying to execute an operator from code (like calling `bpy.ops.my_operator()`) and I'd like to show its UNDO-REDO panel.

(The OT's panel is showing as expected when I execute the operator via search-bar or via button in the UI, it has the `UNDO` option).

I need to call `my_operator` from a diferent operator (**explained below why***) (lets call it `my_other_operator`). `my_other_operator` has not the UNDO option, by the way.

I've tried:

```
bpy.ops.gpencil.my_operator()
bpy.ops.gpencil.my_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
bpy.ops.gpencil.my_operator('EXEC_DEFAULT')
```

But none of them work, they all execute the operator but they don't show the UNDO panel anymore.

Any idea how to show the menu again?

*If someone wants to know the context, I'm using different curves and color ramps that I get from a material. I can't show them in the OT's UNDO panel, and since the UNDO deletes their changes, I've made a "Re-Execute" operator that makes a backup of the values, handles the undo, and calls the operator again (so I would like to make the panel visible again).

Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. To get this functionality you should add the 'UNDO' key word to your operator's 'bl_options'.

---

- In the Blender's text editor there are a plenty of templates. Check out the one called "Operator Mesh Add". You can find it HERE:

[image: undo_01]

---

- And there you can see an example how to implemented the UNDO :

[image: undo_02]

---

- If you want to have a deeper understanding of this topic I can recommend you the Blender's official tutorial which is called "Your Own Operator -- Scripting for Artists" [=[link_to_youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xscQ9tcN4GI)=]

---

Comment: Thanks for the help mate. Yeah, I said in my post that I set the UNDO bl_option, but what I meant is how to make the menu appear when I call the operator from code (the menu shows as expected when I execute the operator as usual).  Sorry if I didn't expres myself correctly